# How to get several regex groups from Matcher in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I have a Java program that does some String matching. I'm looking for anything that matches `\d+x\d+` in a String. This works, using the `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes. However, to parse the `String` parts I have found, I have to manually parse the `String` I get from the `Matcher.find()` and `Matcher.group()`. How can I tell the `Pattern` I'm looking for something in the form of `(\d+)x(\d+)` and get the `Matcher` to return those groups separately?
So instead of the string "1x23" I want to get two strings, "1" and "23".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`Matcher.group(int)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group(int)), not [`Matcher.group()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group()).
With the given regex and input, `group(1)` should be "1" and `group(2)` should be "23".

Comment: Note that you need your pattern to be the second one you listed: (\d+)x(\d+) so the matcher knows what are groups.

Comment: Yes, I should have clarified that (since there are two regexes given).